# NVD3 Cumulative Line Chart : How to set different back ground color for specific X axis

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart, cumulative-line-chart

I am using NVD3 Cumulative Line Chart,it works perfect for me but i want to set different background color to highlight some specific hour on X axis as i have shown in below image.
[image]

OR set different background for graph for particular part
[image]
As shown in above, **i want to set different X - Axis color for specific time period**.

So show me any possible way for do that or any possible way for this requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, and I don't have time to distill it into one right now, but maybe look to https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/80d85f78a5a975fa29d7#file-code-r for guidance. They are using rcharts with nvd3, but I think there is enough to go on there to help you along. You'll have to come up with your own implementation of something like drawVerticalLines, but you should be able to use the general outline.

Comment: [This](https://djaodjin.com/blog/two-background-colors-nvd3-line-chart.blog.html) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, pretty big hack here but you could parse out the location of the axis and add it yourself:

```
var startTick = 1,
      endTick = 3;
  var x1 = parseFloat(d3.select(d3.selectAll('.nv-x .tick')[0][startTick]).attr('transform').split("(")[1]);
  var x2 = parseFloat(d3.select(d3.selectAll('.nv-x .tick')[0][endTick]).attr('transform').split("(")[1]);
  d3.select('.nv-y .tick')
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', x1)
    .attr('x2', x2)
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', 10);
```

**EDITS**

I just re-thought this.  Instead of parsing location out of the DOM you can get it back from the chart object.  Much cleaner this way:

```
var x1 = chart.xScale()(1122782400000);
var x2 = chart.xScale()(1251691200000);
var height = chart.yAxis.range()[0];

// line on x-axis
d3.select('.nv-y .tick')
  .append('line')
  .attr('x1', x1)
  .attr('x2', x2)
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', 10);

// shaded background
d3.select('.nv-y')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', x1)
  .attr('width', x2 - x1)
  .style('fill', 'steelblue')
  .style('opacity', 0.2)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('height', height);
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkg5E7tlGSzyM2QqevsJ?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works fine for me, one more thing is How can we do it for X axis or say for `.nv-x`..?

Comment: @Vijay, see updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkg5E7tlGSzyM2QqevsJ?p=preview)